# how to get value from repeating group in quickfixj

Tags: java, quickfixj

i have question about how to get repeating group value like MDEntryPx from marketsnapshot refresh in fix44
my broker have sent `8=FIX.4.4^A9=198^A35=W^A34=4^A49=OZ_UAT_Q^A52=20200506-02:35:16.521^A56=DXTR_UAT_Q^A55=XAUUSD^A262=eYZDMS^A268=2^A269=0^A270=82.18^A271=1000000^A276=A^A282=FD1^A299=78781576^A269=1^A270=82.38^A271=1000000^A276=A^A282=FD1^A299=78781577^A10=035^A`

how to get value of 270

tag 270 is one of member group

```
 <group name='NoMDEntries' required='Y'>
                <field name='MDEntryType' required='Y' />
                <field name='MDEntryPx' required='N' />
                <field name='Currency' required='N' />
                <field name='MDEntrySize' required='N' />
                <field name='MDEntryDate' required='N' />
                <field name='MDEntryTime' required='N' />
```

i have try using

```
double price = message.getDouble(MDEntryPx.FIELD);
         String priceAsString = String.valueOf(price);
```

but i cannot get value of that price. so how to get that price from repeating group?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've never read the docs about repeating groups.

https://quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.1.0/usage/repeating_groups.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use StringTokenizer to separate FIX tags and then Split functional to get name value pair of tags, so from this you can get your required tag 270 or any tag.

```
public static void ParseFixString() {


    String fixString = "8=FIX.4.4^A9=198^A35=W^A34=4^A49=OZ_UAT_Q^A52=20200506-02:35:16.521^A56=DXTR_UAT_Q^A55=XAUUSD^A262=eYZDMS^A268=2^A269=0^A270=82.18^A271=1000000^A276=A^A282=FD1^A299=78781576^A269=1^A270=82.38^A271=1000000^A276=A^A282=FD1^A299=78781577^A10=035^A";
    String sDelimeter = "^A";
    StringTokenizer mytoken = new   StringTokenizer(fixString,sDelimeter);
    String sTag=null;

    while (mytoken.hasMoreTokens()) {  
         sTag = mytoken.nextToken();  

         if(sTag!=null) {
             String[] aTag =  sTag.split("=");
             if(aTag!=null && aTag.length==2) {

                 //you can put your required  tag comparison here...

                System.out.println("Tag =" + aTag[0] + "   Value=" + aTag[1]);
             }
         }
         //System.out.println(mytoken);

     }  
}
```

Comment: Are you new to QuickFIX?  You don't have to convert the Message object to a string first.  That's kind of crazy.

Comment: well, I had gave a options he has mentioned he gets FIX string as mentioned in same given on his question.  I am a developer worked on FIX 4 to 5.0 for years. Even after Quck fix paser to your business logic code it can come string as he mentioned in sample.